# HTML button onclick function not working with jQuery variable as argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, json.net

```
success: function(jsonresponse) {
    data = JSON.stringify(jsonresponse);

  $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (index, item) {
    var Id=item.id;
    var JobId=item.JobId;

 var eachrow = "<tr>"
             + "<td>" + item.id + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + item.JobId + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + item.UserId + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + item.updatedAt + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + "<button onclick='myFunction(JobId,Id, \"accepted\")' class='btn btn-success btn-block'>Reject</button>" + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + "<button onclick='myFunction(JobId,Id, \"rejected\")' class='btn btn-success btn-block'>Reject</button>" + "</td>"
             + "</tr>";

 $('#tbody2').append(eachrow);
 });

},
```

myFuntion(JobId,Id,\"accepted\") does not works with variable as parameter but when manually added then the function works, like myFuntion(1,3,\"accepted\").

Comment: It's because you are appending the buttons in the wrong way as the variables as string inside the onclick attribute of buttons..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem :** You are not concatenating the `JobId` & `Id` in your HTML Code?

**Solution :**
Properly concatenate your `JobId` & `Id` variables in your HTML code and you will be good to go as :

```
success: function(jsonresponse) {
    data = JSON.stringify(jsonresponse);

  $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (index, item) {
    var Id=item.id;
    var JobId=item.JobId;

 var eachrow = "<tr>"
             + "<td>" + item.id + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + item.JobId + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + item.UserId + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + item.updatedAt + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + "<button onclick='myFunction("+JobId+","+Id+", \"accepted\")' class='btn btn-success btn-block'>Reject</button>" + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + "<button onclick='myFunction("+JobId+","+Id+", \"rejected\")' class='btn btn-success btn-block'>Reject</button>" + "</td>"
             + "</tr>";

 $('#tbody2').append(eachrow);
 });

},
```

Comment: tried with your solution but the myFunction still does not work

Comment: There may be something wrong in your code can you share a link to your code live???

Comment: If what you are saying is right that your function works when you manually put the values in your Function so then you need to do an inspect on your buttons if the values are been printed in there or not??